# Лежит ли точка в треугольнике?

Tags: java

[image: точки]

По учёбе нужно создать программу, которая могла бы вычислить находится ли точка в заданном треугольнике. Даются две точки и это является инпутом, но я сам уверен, что эта программа не подходит условиям для полного выполнения.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    double y = scan.nextDouble();
    if (x <= 200) {
      if (y <= 50)
        System.out.println("The point is in the triangle");
      else
        System.out.println("The point is not in the triangle");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Эта программа даже близко не делает то что надо.

Comment: Даются не две точки, а координаты одной точки. Или вы имели ввиду что-то другое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
double x = scan.nextDouble();
double y = scan.nextDouble();

if(y > 100 - x / 2 || x < 0 || y < 0) {
    System.out.println("Out");
} else {
    System.out.println("In");
}
```

`100 - 1/2 * x` - формула прямой гипотенузы. Если на данной абсциссе точка выше, то она вне, иначе - в.
При хоть одной отрицательной координате(`x` или `y`) точка, разумеется, в треугольник не попадает.

Comment: @Эникейщик для данного треугольника - правильно. Для любого это решение, разумеется, не подойдет

Comment: @Эникейщик код не запускал, но как минимум формула точно правильная для неотрицательных координат (UPD: уже и для отрицательных)

Comment: @Miron да, ошибся я.

Comment: @andreymal, формула - возможно, а программа? Как по-твоему, чему в джаве равно `1/2`?

Comment: О, теперь правильно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, ваше условие получше будет. Стащу-ка я его у вас (`y > 100 - x/2` -> `2 * y > 200 - x`)

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотя подождите, `1 / 2` выводит `0.5`. Неужели где-то хвост?

Comment: @Miron, где `0.5`? https://ideone.com/jhQX8A. Я просто область выбирал. По идее в double с делением ничем не хуже.

Comment: @Qwertiy а, это. Я автоматом к даблу привел.

Answer (score 4):

## Условие:

```
x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 200 - x >= 2 * y
```

## Проверка:

```js
var xs = [-1, 0, 1, 49, 50, 51, 99, 100, 101, 149, 150, 151, 199, 200, 201]
var ys = [-1, 0, 1, 49, 50, 51, 99, 100, 101].reverse()

var res = ""

for (var y of ys) {
  res += `<tr><th>${y}`

  for (var x of xs) {
    res += `<td class=${x >= 0 && y >= 0 && 200 - x >= 2 * y}>`
  }
  
  res += `</tr>`
}

res += `<tr><th>${xs.map(x => `<th>${x}`).join("")}</tr>`
document.body.innerHTML = `<table>${res}</table>`
```

```css
th, td { width: 2em; height: 1em; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1em; }
.true { background: green; }
.false { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 3):

1, 2, 3 - вершины треугольника, 0 - точка

```
(x1 - x0) * (y2 - y1) - (x2 - x1) * (y1 - y0)
(x2 - x0) * (y3 - y2) - (x3 - x2) * (y2 - y0)
(x3 - x0) * (y1 - y3) - (x1 - x3) * (y3 - y0)
```

Если они одинакового знака, то точка внутри треугольника, если что-то из этого - ноль, то точка лежит на стороне, иначе точка вне треугольника.

[источник](https://www.cyberforum.ru/showthread.php?t=8234)